# How is it possible to change whole style in different devices?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, responsive-design

I'm working on a web app using version 4 of Angular.

I want to show a different style for smaller devices and large screen devices. For example, when a user is browsing on mobile size device, the page will be very long which is not good in UX point, but it would be better if I could convert that long page to tabs that user can swipe between them (like menus). Is there any known way by bootstrap or any technique in Angular 4 to helps me for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query and either create a separate file for each:

```
//index.html

<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 360px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 1080px)" href="tablet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1081px)" href="desktop.css" />
```

or create everything in one file:

```
//style.css

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  //Mobile
}
@media (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 1080px) {
  //Tablet
}
@media (min-width: 1081px) {
  //Desktop
}
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I know this :) I asked about other ways which give me more opportunities. Media queries won't make you new HTML element

Comment: @TypeScriptLearner No, it won't. But you can always create all elements you need and then hide those whose you currently don't need by setting display: none.  However, if you want to do some fancy javascript based on different device sizes I would recommend to use [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)